# Kafka command-line consumer reads, but cannot read through Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have manually created topic `test` with this command:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

and using this command:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
```

I inserted these records:

```
This is a message
This is another message
This is a message2
```

First, I consume messages through the command line like this:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

and all the records are successfully shown. Then, I try to implement a consumer in Java using this code:

```
public class KafkaSubscriber {

    public void consume() {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test-consumer-group");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        Consumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("test"));
        // also with this command
        // consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("test"));

        System.out.println("Starting to read data...");

        try {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
                    System.out.println("Number of records found: " + records.count());
                    for (ConsumerRecord rec : records) {
                        System.out.println(rec.value());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            consumer.close();
        }
}
```

But the output is:

```
Starting to read data...
0
0
0
0
0
....
```

Which means that it does not find any records in topic `test`. I also tried to publish some records *after* the Java consumer has started, but the same again. Any ideas what might be going wrong?

---

**EDIT**: After adding the following line:

```
 props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
```

the consumer now reads only when I write new records to the topic. It does not read all the records from the beggining.

Comment: Can you please add `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` as `earliest` in the properties and then post the result?

Comment: @Bitswazsky I edited my question with the result. It now reads when the  publisher writes something new, but when the consumer starts, it does not read what is already inside the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, if no offsets have previously been committed for the group, the consumer starts at the end topics.

Hence if you are running it after having produced records, it won't receive them.

Notice in your `kafka-console-consumer.sh`, you have the `--from-beginning` flag which forces the consumer to instead start from the beginning of the topic.

One workaround, as suggested in a comment, is to set `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` to `earliest`. However I'd be careful with that setting as your consumer will consume from the start of the topics and this could be a lot of data in a real use case.

The easiest solution is now that you've run your consumer once and it has created a group, you can simply rerun the producer. After that when you run the consumer again it will pick up from its last position which will be before the new producer messages.

On the other hand, if you mean to always reconsume all messages then you have 2 options:

- explicitely use `seekToBeginning()` when your consumer starts to move its position to the start of topics
- set `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest` and disable auto offset commit by setting `enable.auto.commit` to `false`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I want is when the consumer starts to read everything that is already written in the topic. I set `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` to `earliest` but now the consumer reads only after the publisher writes something new.

Comment: In that case, you have 2 options:

1) explicitely use seekToBeginning() when your consumer starts to move its position to the start of topics 
otherwise 2) set auto.offset.reset to earliest and disable offset commit